# Why does @unset give a parse error?

Tags: php, parsing

Why can't you hide errors with the `@` operator when calling `unset`? The following results in a parse error:

```
@unset($myvar);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error suppression operator only works on expressions:

`unset` is a language construct and not a function, so `@` cannot be used.

Answer (score 10):

The `@` operator only works on expressions, and `unset` is a language construct, not a function. See the [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) for more information:

> Note: The @-operator works only on
> expressions. A simple rule of thumb
> is: if you can take the value of
> something, you can prepend the @
> operator to it. For instance, you can
> prepend it to variables, function and
> include() calls, constants, and so
> forth. You cannot prepend it to
> function or class definitions, or
> conditional structures such as if and
> foreach, and so forth.

Answer (score 5):

You can hide errors by prefixing @ to functions/statements. However unset is a language construct, therefore it doesn't support the @-rule.

The good thing is that unset() never fails even if the variable didn't exist to begin with, so this shouldn't be necessary.

As nightcracker mentionned though, using @ is pretty bad practice.

Comment: Not entirely correct - `unset($undefined)` won't fail, but `unset($undefined['foo'])` will.

Comment: True that, but if you don't initialize arrays you have other issues imo :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't you hide errors with the @ operator when calling unset?

I do not know. But you should not be using the error suppression operator (@) anyway. There are two distinct scenarios:

#### Developemnt

You want to see *all errors right at the moment they happen*, preferably with the raw error message that PHP gives you.

#### Production

You want to let *no PHP error message bubble to the user*. Instead you want to log the PHP error message and display your own message that a layman can understand.

You cannot achieve this distinction when you use @. You should separate theses scenarios by configuring [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and setting an error handler with [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).